# Show which modifier keys are pressed during screen recording?

Tags: windows-7, recording, tablet-pc, modifier-keys

I'd like to see which modifier keys I've pressed during screen recordings so my students can understand what keys I've pressed while I click and drag.

Is there any software that can do this?

I'm aware that Windows 7 does this internally, if there's a way to enable it.

---

### Windows 7

When you have a Wacom tablet connected to your PC, or if you have a Tablet PC, windows shows little yellow tip bubbles whenever you press modifier keys.

Any way to enable these on a normal PC?

[image: tips]

**Update:**

- I've tried starting the Tablet PC Input Service but nothing happens.
- The [Tablet PC Settings](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/67799-tablet-pc-settings-shortcut-create.html) dialog has nothing interesting either.

Is there a registry setting I can tweak?

[image: services]

Answer (score 0):

Something like [ShowOff](http://www.donationcoder.com/Software/Skrommel/index.html#ShowOff)?  Never used it, but recently stumbled upon it.